# Common and profile specific properties in a single application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

I am writing a spring mvc application. I want to make use of spring profiles' features. I want to have a single application.properties with common and profile specific properties. I also want to have a set a default profile in the same file. How do i do this?

Comment: Why a single file... There is already a naming convention for properties files. If you really want a single file use an `application.yml` file instead. I would say work with the framework instead of around it.

Comment: Using yaml, spring allows all the common and profile specific props to be there in a single file. However, the same is not possible using .properties. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extra spring configuration class to dynamically return the properties based on the spring profile:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class QuotePropertyConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public String getMySpecificProperty() {
        return environment.getProperty("myprop." + Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()) + ".thing");
    }
}
```

That will return you e.g. myprop.dev.thing, myprop.test.thing, myprop.prod.thing etc. depending on the active spring profiles.

Alternatively you can also do this with multiple application.properties files: From the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties):

> In addition to application.properties files, profile-specific
>   properties can also be defined using the naming convention
>   application-{profile}.properties. The Environment has a set of default
>   profiles (by default [default]) which are used if no active profiles
>   are set (i.e. if no profiles are explicitly activated then properties
>   from application-default.properties are loaded).